# Drag and drop events in embedded SVG?

Tags: drag-and-drop, svg, google-closure, clojurescript

Is there any possibility of receiving drag and drop events from SVG elements within a web page?

I tried the Google Closure library, to no avail.

Specifically, suppose my page contains

```
<ul id = "list">
  <li class="item" id="item1">foo</li>
  <li class="item">bar</li>
  <li class="item">baz</li>
</ul>
```

And my script contains (Clojurescript/C2)

```
(let [items (select-all ".item")
      lst (select "#list")
      target (fx/DragDrop. lst nil)]
  (dorun (map
    (fn [item]
      (let [source (fx/DragDrop. item nil)]
        (. source (addTarget target))
        (. source (init))))
    items))
  (. target (init)))
```

Then I *do* get a drag image (ghost), although I do not manage to receive drag events e.g. by doing

```
(on-raw "#item1" :dragstart (fn [e] (.log js/console (str "dragstart " e))))
```

Using similar code for SVG elements, I do not even get a ghost...

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Drag events are not supported on SVG Elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html#RelationshipWithDOM2Events.

You can fake the drag events with mouse events, see http://svg-whiz.com/svg/DragAndDrop.svg (view the source).

Comment: I know that this is not part of the standard, but I had hoped that a few browsers would start supporting it, and/or that a JS library encapsulating drag-and-drop for SVG would be available... Thanks for the example though!

Comment: Opera does support drag events on svg elements (same as for other HTML5 elements).

Comment: Indeed it does! The issue is that my code, or C2, or Google closure and Opera do not seem to get along very well (I get strange errors related to `webkitMatchesSelector` or something...). Do you know if other browsers will follow suit?

Comment: Also, it seems that Chromium does fire at least a few drag events, but does not draw ghosts. Is there a way of troubleshooting this?

Comment: hmm, mouse events for drag and drop are not even handled on android. You may want to use `pointerevent` instead, which according to documentation should be a merge of mouse events and touch events. But still no success. then tried `style="touch-action: none"` to surpress default browser pinching behavior of android. But still ... no succes.

Answer (score 2):

You can always implement it. Basically, you have to check if the element is touching another one when you are dragging:

```
this.isTouching = function(element){
        if(this.x <= element.x && element.x <= (this.x + this.width) && 
           this.y <= element.y && element.y <= (this.y + this.height)){
           return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    };
```

And it works in all browsers. Hope it helps :)