# Drag and drop one image inside 2 `svg` circles (back and forth)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, drag-and-drop

I am trying  to `drag and drop` a `logo` into 2 `SVG circles`. From the help of my code, the image is being dragged into one circle ,but it's not getting dragged to another circle.

How to modify the [code](https://codepen.io/teddcp/pen/MWWzgRa)  so that the **image can be dragged/dropped between 2 circles**?

```js
function drag(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function allow(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
     var img1=document.getElementById(data),
         imgSrc=img1.getAttribute('src'),
         imgw=img1.getAttribute('width')
         imgh=img1.getAttribute('height'),
         imgX = ev.target.getAttribute('cx') - ev.target.getAttribute('r')+20;
         console.log(imgX);
         ev.target.parentElement.innerHTML += '<image xlink:href="' + imgSrc + '" x="' + imgX + '" y="0" width="' + imgw + 'px" height="' + imgh + 'px"/>';
         img1.parentNode.removeChild(img1);

     //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Assignment1_HTML_L2</title>
 
</head>
<body>
   <div id="circle" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allow(event)" >
 <svg width="1000" height="200">
    <circle id="c1" cx="70" cy="50" r="50" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="4"  style="opacity: 1;" /> 

    <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" stroke="yellow"  fill="white" stroke-width="4"  style="opacity: 1;"/>
   </svg>
  </div>
  <image id="p1" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l3vR16pONsV8cKkWk/giphy.gif" alt="picture" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="30" height="30" style="opacity: 1;">

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE :**

Posted the link of SVG file in the answer section !!

Comment: why don't you apply CSS circles instead of SVG circles? I have done it using CSS circles.

Comment: @VSM  That's assignment question :)

Comment: @VSM if possible, can you share it?

Comment: Still trying to handle drag and drop within SVG. If you need I can share that feature within CSS circles.

Comment: @VSM i have posted one answer . Please have a look and let me know if it works.
Thanks for bearing with me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `draggable`/`ondragstart`etc are HTML attributes. They don't work in SVGs.  So you'll need to implement the dragging using standard mouse events.

See: [Drag and drop events in embedded SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283183/drag-and-drop-events-in-embedded-svg)

And thre are many other questions on S.O. related to implementing dragging in SVGs.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Paul, i found the answer. Make sure that the file extension should be in svg. Also you can include it in html.

[File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IMGhLYHO-8KwjKVvx-dhFGKKlAx2J1_Y/view?usp=sharing)